# Installing Python on WIndows 10 64 bit

Tags: python

I w as trying to install python on my 64 bit Windows 10 machine. I downloaded the latest Python 2 release(following Zed Shaw's book, thus not installing Python 3). After installation was complete, I entered python in power shell. I however get the following error.

```
PS C:\> python
python : Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 2.7.10 (...MD64)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The shell takes no more input. I'm forced to use Ctrl+C. I know this is extremely basic but I cant seem to figure it out by googling the error.

Comment: try entering it in the command line instead.

Comment: Thanks @James_Parsons, works with command prompt, but i'll still like to make it work with power shell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are your environment variables set correctly?

See the following post where a user had a similar issue:

[I'm trying to use python in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell)

Try typing this in your powershell console as well:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

Also according to this document, you may need to update your powershell profile:

https://superuser.com/questions/437790/run-python-scripts-in-powershell-directly