# Visual Studio Code's PowerShell cannot find my Python

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code

For a particular machine learning project, I needed to install **Python 3.5** instead of the typical **Python 3.6** I usually use. I set up my path variables such that within the command line or PowerShell, `python` launches my typical Anaconda Python 3.6, but `python35` launches my Python 3.5 edition.

My favorite text editor / lightweight IDE to use is **Visual Studio Code**. However, when I use Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal to execute my Python scripts, it's unable to find my 3.5 edition.

Using Windows Powershell, things work completely fine:
[image]

However, when I attempt to access Python 3.5 within my Visual Studio Code PowerShell terminal, it can't recognize `python35`:
[image]

I've Google searched my the error ("the term ... is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,..."), but every post I found on SO related to this issue ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell)) has been about setting environment variables. I don't think this is the case here, since my normal PowerShell is able to recognize both `python` and `python35`. My suspicion is this has to do with the internal workings of the integrated terminal feature in Visual Studio Code, but I don't know enough to understand what to do next.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It's not a mission-critical issue, since I just pull up my PowerShell to execute my Python scripts, but I'd like to solve it for curiosity's sake.

Comment: Compare `$env:PATH` in both environments. The VSCode PowerShell extension doesn't load your regular `$PROFILE`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue - although with Jekyll and not Python. My Path variables are the same.

Comment: No, I didn't bother since an easy fix was just switching to my `cmd` or moving to PyCharm. But I think @mklement0 is pretty spot on, although if you say your path variables are the same for both then I'm stumped.

Comment: @rorymadden, maybe it is obvious but in my case the key part was noticing the little yellow warning sign at the status bar (bottom) of VSC which I clicked and then selected **which** python I would like to use out of two. After then everything worked fine.