# Error when running Python in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

> python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

I have downloaded Python 3 and the extension. I have shut down VScode and restarted. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to use python in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell)

Comment: did you set the path variable?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! At present, your question does not have enough information to give a good answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If running a pythin file in the terminal please use the comnand "Python Run current file in terminal". Also Please ensure you have configured the Python interpreter, check the following documentation. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments.

Comment: Same problem here. I have followed all the instructions in the hello world tutorial, but the python interpreter cannot be found in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

First, check if python is added to the path(python does this during the installation).
If the path is properly added and still you are facing the issue, then VS Code is looking at the wrong place. use this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) to select the path added by python(or you) then run it.