# Running a python script via Powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

I have a python script which I can run via PowerShell using the following code:

```
cd User\PythonScripts
python TestFile.py
```

Now I want to run these simple commands via a PowerShell script (notepad file and saving it as a `ps1` file).

I have googled a lot but I cannot find an answer, but I think it should be something like this:

```
$path = 'C:\User\PythonScripts'
$file = 'TestFile.py
```

I think I still miss the reference to python (so it knows which program he needs). How do I need to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide more details in your [mcve]. As currently written, it's a bit unclear what do you asking for.  Maybe reading `powershell -?` could help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that python is already in your path variables you can just call a python script like this:

```
python C:\User\PythonScripts\TestFile.py
```

Comment: Great, just a simple line of code but it works! Now I only need to hit Run with powershelll. Thanks

Comment: Placing python in path is no longer optimal. Consider py launcher instead. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/75139069/10141885.

Answer (score 7):

I think the question is you want to run the python script using powershell .

I think below code will do for you

```
$path = 'C:\User\PythonScripts'
$file = 'TestFile.py'

$cmd = $path+"\\"+$file  # This line of code will create the concatenate the path and file
Start-Process $cmd  # This line will execute the cmd
```

Save the above code as `.ps1` and run the that powershell file

Comment: or just this - "py $path+"\\"+$file" in the .ps1 file would do.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same problem with Windows10 PowerShell and I have solved it like this:

Go to PowerShell and instead of running the command like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> python ex1.py
```

run it as below:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> python C:\Users\PCWIZARD\Desktop\hardway\ex1.py
```

In other words specify the entire path of your `ex1.py` depending on where you saved your file on your computer. This will print out your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think below code will work.

cd C:\User\PythonScripts

.\python TestFile.py

Mention python.exe if it is a executable in place of python.
Save above code in .ps1 file and run it on powershell