# Powershell not recognized the python

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables

In my pc python is install and show in cmd but not show in powershell

output of cmd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JLjv.png

output of powershell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmioH.png

output of system variables in (path)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WKRd.png

output of user variables in (path)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL9Qe.png

how power shell recognized python ?
please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to use python in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813435/im-trying-to-use-python-in-powershell)

Comment: Please [do not post images of code as this is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)  ... you may take the [Tour] and at least read the help topic [Ask] a good question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart powershell after installing python? Try exec `Get-Command python`.

Comment: you have not shown what the path values are _inside powershell_. please, add to your Question the TEXT [not an image] from >>> `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath env:\` while in the PoSh console.